# How to get soundcloud files to work with Sound Manager 2?

Tags: javascript, html, audio-streaming, soundmanager2

My current setup with sound manager works for all my mp3 links except for ones with soundcloud sources.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, anyone see something wrong with my code?

```
<!-- Page player core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soundmanager2/page-player.css" />

<!-- soundManager.useFlashBlock: related CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soundmanager2/flashblock.css" />

<!-- optional: annotations/sub-tracks/notes, and alternate themes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soundmanager2/optional-annotations.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="soundmanager2/optional-themes.css" />



<!-- soundManager API -->
<script src="soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js"></script>

<script>


soundManager.setup({
  flashVersion: 9,
  preferFlash: true, // for visualization effects
  useHighPerformance: true, // keep flash on screen, boost performance
  wmode: 'transparent', // transparent SWF, if possible
  url: 'soundmanager2/'
});

// custom page player configuration

var PP_CONFIG = {
  autoStart: false,      // begin playing first sound when page loads
  playNext: true,        // stop after one sound, or play through list until end
  useThrottling: false,  // try to rate-limit potentially-expensive calls (eg. dragging position around)</span>
  usePeakData: true,     // [Flash 9 only] whether or not to show peak data (left/right channel values) - nor noticable on CPU
  useWaveformData: false,// [Flash 9 only] show raw waveform data - WARNING: LIKELY VERY CPU-HEAVY
  useEQData: false,      // [Flash 9 only] show EQ (frequency spectrum) data
  useFavIcon: false     // try to apply peakData to address bar (Firefox + Opera) - performance note: appears to make Firefox 3 do some temporary, heavy disk access/swapping/garbage collection at first(?) - may be too heavy on CPU
}


</script>

<!-- Page player main script -->
<script src="soundmanager2/page-player.js"></script>
```

Then I use it in my body here

```
<div>

 <ul class="playlist">


 <li> <a href="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/63928998/stream?client_id=bcc10d97babdd9960f823530831e0eb9d&q">SongName</a></li>


 </ul>

 <div id="control-template">
  <!-- control markup inserted dynamically after each link -->
  <div class="controls">
   <div class="statusbar">
    <div class="loading"></div>
     <div class="position"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timing">
   <div id="sm2_timing" class="timing-data">
    <span class="sm2_position">%s1</span> / <span class="sm2_total">%s2</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="peak">
   <div class="peak-box"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="spectrum-container" class="spectrum-container">
  <div class="spectrum-box">
   <div class="spectrum"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please do not post [multiple copies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981863/sound-manager-2-not-loading-soundcloud-files-properly) of your question just because you received a down-vote.

Comment: i didn't i just posted this one to show my actual code because the other one didn't have it

Comment: You can edit your post to add the code. There is no need to post multiple times.

Comment: man, do you even know how to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

In short, your SoundCloud links are not direct links to a .mp3 file but are links to their API that then returns a one-time link to the files.

It is similar to a link to a file on a file sharing website, you get a link to webpage which generates a one-time link to the file to prevent hot-linking.

Because of this, and your current setup it is not possible to play SoundCloud links direct in the browser.

Comment: I'm aware of this, it is a problem with cross domain xml, there are ways around it with programs like python im guessing, I was just wondering if anyone knew a way that would get me around it. This website is meant for helping people, i came here to get help from an experienced expert programmer. Why i use this site anyway.

Comment: @user2276158 I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with X-Domain XML, I believe it is simply that the URL does not end in a music format or is not a direct link to the music file so your player system does not recognise it.

Comment: but that is the direct link to the stream url when you decodes its json, the problem is when you go to that link even if you input it in a browser it redirects you to something like this "http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/0DZjJ7jZ9uDE.128.mp3?ff61182e3c2ecefa438cd02102d0e385713f0c1faf3b0339595665ff0600e814cc600e1bae5d71554600232882c2ee67594752b9169b101a8a44c32e54a7f4c7f599fd584b&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1365953086&Signature=xx9yCanHj691AIfY20MKEtO2c%2BU%3D"  There has to be a way to input the stream url link and allow the redirect without opening a seperate page

Comment: @user2276158 Even that in it's self is not a direct link. You can tell from the ?[values] after .mp3.

Comment: Okay but I think it's a redirect problem because it creates a API then links you to another link. Wouldn't you just have to redirect it back to the soud manager?

Comment: Your terminology is a bit mixed up. It does not create an API, there is already an API in place and that is what the link is. I believe that SoundManager does not support the link.